# Probelm with my webapp, how can I solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, streamlit

I have a small big problem with an app I have created, using Python and Streamlit.
The problem is that when I want to deploy it to the Heroku services, it builds, but when I try to access it, it tells me that there is an applicaiton error.

I have looked at my code, whcih on the local machine works pefectly.

Do you have any idea?

Code:

```
# Loading packages ##########################################################################
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from pyvis.network import Network


# import plotly.express as px
###############################################################################################
st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

##### Creazione Sidebar ####################################################################
st.sidebar.title('Ottimizzazione')
st.sidebar.header('Creazione matrice')
st.sidebar.write('Scrivere la matrice quadrata come da esempio Matrice: 1,2;4,5')
st.sidebar.write('Usare la , per separe le varie colonne e il ; per andare alla prossima riga')
input_matrice=st.sidebar.text_area('Scrivere Matrice:')

# Creazione matrice
matrice = np.matrix(input_matrice)
matrice_array = np.asarray(matrice)

##### Creazione Due colonne per output ##############################################################
left_column1, right_column1 = st.beta_columns(2)
left_column2, right_column2 = st.beta_columns(2)

## Visualizzazione matrice
with left_column1:
    st.header('Matrice Quadrata Creata:')
    matrice_array
with right_column1: 
    st.header('Visualizzazione del grafo:')
    st.write('Il grafo verrà visualizzato in una apgina separata, in quanto al momento non riuslta possible integrarlo nella pagina pricipale')  

##### Creaizone Input per calcolo #######################################################
st.sidebar.header('Calcolo percorso:')
st.sidebar.write('Calcolo del percorso più corto, Nx nodo di partenza e Ny nodo di arrivo. I nodi della matrice corrispondono agli indici della colonna.')
selezione = st.sidebar.radio("Seleziona tipo di calcolo",('Da Nx a tutti più vicini','Da Nx a Ny'))
if selezione == 'Da Nx a tutti più vicini':
    nodo_partenza=np.int(st.sidebar.number_input('Scrivere nodo di partenza (Numero intero):'))
    bottone_calcolo = st.sidebar.button('Calcola percorso', key=1)
    if bottone_calcolo:
        grafo_matrice = nx.from_numpy_matrix(matrice_array)
        percorso = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path(grafo_matrice, nodo_partenza, weight='weight')
        lunghezza = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(grafo_matrice, nodo_partenza, weight='weight')
        with left_column2:
            st.header('Percorsi:')
            st.write('Qui vengono mostrati i vari percorsi che sono stati trovati. I valori a destra corrispondono al ordine di successione, mentre I valori a destra i vari nodi.') 
            percorso
        with right_column2:
            st.header('Tempi percorsi:')
            st.write('Qui vengono mostrati i vari tempi dei vari percorsi')
            lunghezza
        with right_column1:
            nt=Network("1000px","1000px")
            nt.from_nx(grafo_matrice)
            nt.show("nx.html")
elif selezione == 'Da Nx a Ny':
    nodo_partenza=np.int(st.sidebar.number_input('Scrivere nodo di partenza (Numero intero):'))
    nodo_arrivo=np.int(st.sidebar.number_input('Scrivere nodo di arrivo (Numero intero):'))
    bottone_calcolo = st.sidebar.button('Calcola percorso', key=2)
    if bottone_calcolo:
        grafo_matrice = nx.from_numpy_matrix(matrice_array)
        percorso = nx.shortest_path(grafo_matrice, source=nodo_partenza, target=nodo_arrivo, weight='weight')
        lunghezza = nx.shortest_path_length(grafo_matrice, source=nodo_partenza, target=nodo_arrivo, weight='weight')
        with left_column2:
            st.header('Percorso:')
            st.write('Qui viene mostrato il percorso trovato. I valori a destra corrispondono al ordine di successione, mentre I valori a destra i vari nodi.')
            percorso
        with right_column2:
            st.header('Tempo percorso:')
            st.write('Qui viene mostrato il tempo totale del pecrorso più breve')
            lunghezza
        with right_column1:
            nt=Network("1000px","1000px")
            nt.from_nx(grafo_matrice)
            nt.show("nx.html")
```

Requirements:

```
streamlit==0.75.0
numpy==1.19.2
networkx==2.5.0
pyvis==0.1.9
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify the question.  "There is an application error?"  Is that the exact message?  What command was issued that caused that result?  What other details can you provide besides the above code?  How are you deploying?  What options are you useing?  Et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, it appear the problem was not in the code, but inside the command of the code for running the webapp